# Is vocal voice in tone Em the same with tone F#m in a song?

Tags: voice-leading

Please explain to answer this question: - Is tone Em the same with tone F#m in a song?

Comment: What do you mean by a "tone" and what do you mean by asking whether two tones are "the same"? Obviously E minor and F# minor are two different chords - they are not "the same". Also the key of E minor and the key of F# minor are not "the same". But presumably you mean something else...

Comment: Hello James, thanks for your input. My question should be like this: "Is vocal voice in tone Em the same with vocal voice in tone F#m to sing a song?

Answer (score 3):

Neither Em nor F#m are tones, they're chords.

Em contains the tones E, G, B.

F#m contains F#, A, C#.

[image: Em and F#m chords in a staff]

None of these are the same tone or enharmonically equivalent.
(Enharmonically equivalent tones have the same pitch but different name.)

It's really very unclear what you are even trying to ask about.

I wonder it maybe you meant to ask about E# and F, or about E and Fb.

Both E# and F with each other, and E and Fb with each other are enharmonically equivalent, and thus, so are also entire chords of the same kind based on them (E#7 with F7; Em with Fbm; and so on). That means all the pitches are the same, but which one of the pair you *think of* the chord as can depend; generally you denote the one in which you can see some kind of relationship to the song's key, while the other just makes you think "this would be completely out of place here".

Comment: They're also keys, which is a more likely concept to be mistranslated as "tone."